# Web administration of Ejabberd with virtual box and external authentication

Tags: ejabberd

sorry for my long question. Just to figure out the scenario.
I have an Ubuntu host machine where I installed VirtualBox and an Ubuntu guest VM box. The guest has IP address 192.168.56.101. Here I installed a LAMP server with a Web platform written in PHP, and Ejabberd 16.01

Here it is my /etc/hosts on the host machine:

```
192.168.56.101  localmessage.my.website
```

When Ejabberd uses internal authorization, I have no problems. The Ejabberd Web administration panel is reachable by host machine like a charm (through URL https://localmessage.my.website:5280/admin).

After that, I tried to exploit the mySQL database of Web platform for Ejabberd's external authentication. I implemented a PHP file (check_mysql.php) starting from https://github.com/leesherwood/ejabberd-php-auth. I saved it into /var/www directory of guest machine, I set its owner to ejabberd:ejabberd and enabled *execute* permissions.
When I tested the solution by command line (by running *php /var/www/check_mysql.php* and then writing to the prompt *00auth:username:servername:password*, by getting inspirations from https://github.com/leesherwood/ejabberd-php-auth/tree/master/examples/Collection), it works.
But, when I try to reach the Ejabberd's Web admin panel from host machine, I receive authorization error and a loop of requesting admin credentials.
Here is the /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml configuration file on guest machine:

```
loglevel: 4

log_rotate_size: 0
log_rotate_date: ""

log_rate_limit: 100

hosts:
  - "localhost"
  - "localmessage.my.website"

listen: 
  - 
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    certfile: "/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem"
    starttls: true
    protocol_options:
      - "no_sslv3"
    ##   - "no_tlsv1"
    max_stanza_size: 65536
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    zlib: true
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  - 
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
  - 
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/websocket": ejabberd_http_ws
    ##  "/pub/archive": mod_http_fileserver
    web_admin: true
    http_bind: true
    ## register: true
    captcha: true
    tls: true
    certfile: "/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem"

disable_sasl_mechanisms: "digest-md5"

s2s_use_starttls: optional
s2s_certfile: "/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem"
s2s_protocol_options:
  - "no_sslv3"

auth_password_format: plain
auth_method: external
extauth_program: "/var/www/check_mysql.php"

shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000

max_fsm_queue: 1000

acl:
  admin:
     user:
         - "admin": "localhost"
  local: 
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - "127.0.0.0/8"
access:
  max_user_sessions: 
    all: 10
  max_user_offline_messages: 
    admin: 5000
    all: 100
  local: 
    local: allow
  c2s: 
    blocked: deny
    all: allow
  c2s_shaper: 
    admin: none
    all: normal
  s2s_shaper: 
    all: fast
  announce: 
    admin: allow
  configure: 
    admin: allow
  muc_admin: 
    admin: allow
  muc_create: 
    local: allow
  muc: 
    all: allow
  pubsub_createnode: 
    local: allow
  register: 
    all: allow
  trusted_network: 
    loopback: allow

language: "en"

modules: 
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce: # recommends mod_adhoc
    access: announce
  mod_blocking: {} # requires mod_privacy
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {} # requires mod_adhoc
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_echo: {}
  mod_irc: {}
  mod_http_bind: {}
  ## mod_http_fileserver:
  ##   docroot: "/var/www"
  ##   accesslog: "/var/log/ejabberd/access.log"
  mod_last: {}
  mod_muc: 
    ## host: "conference.@HOST@"
    access: muc
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_admin: muc_admin
  ## mod_muc_log: {}
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  ## mod_multicast: {}
  mod_offline: 
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  ## mod_pres_counter:
  ##   count: 5
  ##   interval: 60
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  ## mod_proxy65: {}
  mod_pubsub: 
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    ignore_pep_from_offline: true
    last_item_cache: false
    plugins: 
      - "flat"
      - "hometree"
      - "pep" # pep requires mod_caps
  mod_register: 
    welcome_message: 
      subject: "Welcome!"
      body: |-
        Hi.
        Welcome to this XMPP server.
    ip_access: trusted_network
    access: register
  mod_roster: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stats: {}
  mod_time: {}
  mod_vcard:
    search: false
  mod_version: {}
allow_contrib_modules: true
```

Could you figure out the reason of this error, please?

**EDIT 1**
I checked comments of @Badlop. I had already set `+x` for owner, group and other users. After @Badlop suggestions, I have set loglevel to 5, and tried the *ejabberdctl* command. Here is the result (unfortunately I have to link a screenshot on my GoogleDrive): https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_jWJeulge_q6XYeM3hTGzbavRjjWp19s
Could someone figure out the reason, please?

**EDIT 2**
With the Perl script provided by Ejabberd, as well as with my script, I run the command

```
ejabberdctl check_password user1 localhost mypass11
```

I obtain the same error as previously depicted in **Edit 1**. 
Obviously, I assigned the ejabberd:ejabberd owning, and enabled +x for user, group and others, to each one of the scripts.
I inspected the /var/log/ejabberd/error.log and /var/log/ejabberd.log. Both reports the same error:

```
@extauth:loop:142 extauth script has exitted abruptly with reason 'normal'
```

I moved the Perl as well as my PHP script within the folder /etc/ejabberd. Same error.

Please, help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> When I tested the solution by command line [...], it works.

And, if you check auth with this command, is it accepted (returns 0) or rejected (returns 1)?

```
$ ejabberdctl check_password user1 localhost mypass11
$ echo $?
0
```

Notice that ejabberd does not execute "php yourscript.php", it executes directly "yourscript.php". This means that your script must be an executable file, and the system user that runs ejabberd must have permissions to execute that file. For testing, you can grant everybody permissions to execute that file. Also, set ejabberd loglevel to 5, it may provide some clue about your problem.

Comment: Badlop, thanks for your reply. I already set `+x` for owner, group and other users. I have set loglevel to 5, and tried the suggested command. Here is the result (unfortunately I have to link a screenshot on my GoogleDrive): https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_jWJeulge_q6XYeM3hTGzbavRjjWp19s

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem in the script, or at least in how ejabberd connects to it. Try using the small example script included with ejabberd, written in Perl. If that works, see how the script and ejabberd behave. Then use your custom script, or the one where you are basing yours, and see the differences.